# xaml custom progress bar with images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, progress-bar

I want to make custom animated progress bar using ten images. Now I use a Timer`s Tick that changes resource images every 5 milliseconds:

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Stretch="Fill"
             x:Name="imageProgressBar"/>
   </Grid>
```

C#

```
 private void StartAnimation()
 {
        if (IsAnimating) return;

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = FrameDuration;
        _timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        _timer.Start();
    }


    private void StopAnimation()
    {
        if (!IsAnimating) return;

        _timer.Stop();
        _timer = null;
    }


    private void TimerTick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (FramesCount == 0 || _frames == null) return;

        _currentFrame++;
        _currentFrame = _currentFrame % FramesCount;

        if (_currentFrame < _frames.Count)
            imageProgressBar.Source = _frames[_currentFrame];
    }
```

This variant works, but it is not good enough, because it uses the UI (as I guess) thread for processing, and thats why it`s sometimes slow.
Is there any way to change Source of Image differently?

Comment: It may be the changing and subsequent re-rendering of the images that is slowing things down more than the source. As your need is so particular, it might be worth simply loading all 10 images right away, and then having something change their opacity or visibility in order to achieve whatever effect you're after.

Comment: @dmitriy check this articular of jerrynixon for custom progress ring  [link](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/06/lets-code-build-custom-progress-ring-in.html) hope this helps ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Logan  I just thought about it, but since I'm new with XAML I could not think how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I was creating similar animation using code behind for my project. The problem is in the first cycle when the image needs to be read buffered and loaded it takes time and hence animation starts working properly from second cycle.
The workaround fix that I ended up using was defining the storyboard in XAML itself(as it was easier) and loading images in XAML while updating their Visibility
**XAML Code:**

```
<Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard_Loading" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading1">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading2">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading3">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading4">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading5">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading6">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading7">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading8">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading9">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading10">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading11">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="pageLoading12">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Background="#3F000000">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="GridLoading"  >
            <!--<ProgressRing IsActive="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#EF4D17"/>-->
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_1.png" />
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading1" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_1.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading2" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_2.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading3" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_3.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading4" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_4.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading5" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_5.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading6" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_6.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading7" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_7.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading8" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_8.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading9" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_9.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading10" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_10.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading11" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_11.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="pageLoading12" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ProgressBar/page_loading_12.png"/>
        </Grid>
        <!--<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="GridLoading" Background="#3F000000">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Image_Progress_Bar"   />
        </Grid>-->
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerin that is exactly what I wanted to do!

Comment: Glad to be of help.